# On Windows XP - Change monitor resolution based on which user is logged in?

Tags: windows, resolution, user-profiles, display

In Windows XP Professional, each of our family members are listed as icons at startup.  Is there a way to have the system change the monitor resolution based on the family member?  For example, if 'Dad' is clicked have it render 1028 x 768, if 'Mom' logs in have the monitor resolution set to 800 x 600.  If 'Boy' logs in have the resolution set to 1280×1024 etc...

Comment: Your user profiles are called "Mom", "Dad", and "Boy"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this program : ["XP Keep per User Display Settings"](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sto41/en/My%20Tools/XPKeepPerUserDisplaySettings.htm). I quote:

> The program is launched for each and
>   every user -- don't worry, it's rather
>   small -- and monitors the following
>   events:
>
> - switching among active users
> - users logging off
>
> Each time such an event occurs the
>   current user's display settings are
>   saved in that user's part of the
>   registry.
>   Conversely, each time a user logs in
>   or becomes active, his/her saved
>   settings are restored.

Comment: I just installed this (after scanning it for viruses).  It is working well (and free) which is a big plus over the UltraMon suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't work for dual monitor setups :(

Comment: Added a free suggestion for multi-monitor setups.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**UltraMon**](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)'s [**display profiles**](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp):

> Display profiles make it easy to
>   switch between different desktop
>   configurations. A profile stores the
>   display mode, position and state
>   (enabled/disabled) of each monitor, as
>   well as which monitor is primary
>   (changing the primary is only
>   supported on Windows 2000/XP and
>   later).
>
> **If your computer is used by more than
>   one person, you can use display
>   profiles to set up custom display
>   configurations for each user. Whenever
>   a user logs in, his or her display
>   settings will be applied.** Windows XP
>   Fast User Switching is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-monitor resolution change can be achieved for *free* by using [MultiRes](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/multires.shtm) (115K when installed!) from a batch file called from user logon scripts.

For example, place the following in a batch file (adding users as necessary and call it something like MultiRes.bat):

> `if /I %USERNAME% == USER1 "c:\program files\MultiRes\multires.exe" /1:1280,1024,32,60 /2:1280,1024,32,60 /exit`
>   `if /I %USERNAME% == USER2 "c:\program files\MultiRes\multires.exe" /1:1024,768,32,60 /2:1024,768,32,60 /exit`

Place this batch file in an accessible directory, such as:

> `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\MultiRes.bat`

Add this as a user logon script:

- Open the Group Policy Editor (**Start** -> **Run**, enter **gpedit.msc**)
- In the left-hand tree of the Group Policy window, open **User Configuration**
- Open **Windows Settings**
- Click **Scripts (Logon/Logoff)**
- In the right-hand pane, double-click **Logon**
- In the Logon Properties window, click **Add...**
- Click **Browse...** and select your MultiRes.bat file
- Click **OK** and then **OK** again and close the **Group Policy** window

Please Note: MultiRes is free for personal use only. See above URL for further details.